# How to make a Three.js fullscreen app with a web form/text overlay responsive?

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, three.js

(To be clear i am asking how to make my app **responsive**, not asking how to make it)

So I've been working on a web app that uses Three.js to render a scene using the full window. I want to make a configuration overlay that appears and disappears when you click a settings button. The idea is that this overlay will have some text and some html form elements in it.

I know how to make the overlay, but my struggle is how to get it to display properly on mobile. Generally when making a website behave responsibly on mobile it seems the usual way to go about it is by setting the viewport to be smaller on mobile, through something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It is my understanding that this renders the page by pretending it is only something like 320 pixels wide, even if in reality the mobile device has something like a 900 pixel wide screen.

**The problem** with using this solution is that when I render my fullscreen Three.js scene, it uses the 320 pixels wide, and I end up with a fuzzy image.

I'd like to have a way to somehow set the viewport for my overlay / config form to be smaller on a mobile device, while still maintaining the full definition quality of my rendering of my Three.js scene.

Comment: There are countless things on the interwebs about making a webpage responsive . Search "media queries" on google, it is done via css. The three.js scene is a different matter, it generally is set with something like `renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);` and `renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);`

Comment: Aren't most (all?) of the examples on the [three.js website](https://threejs.org/examples/) responsive? Maybe start with one of those?

Comment: @2pha Thanks! The problem was I didn't know that renderer.setPixelRatio was a thing. Its working well now!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer so this question can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment, Your problems seems to be pixel ratio on high dpi screens.
use something like:

```
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
```